# Extract substrings between two delimiter characters from a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010

I have to extract substrings from a string if the substring is between a start delimiter and an end delimiter.

For e.g.,my string is:

```
12345\Disk&Ven_SRT&Prod_USB_3.0_JET_16G&Rev_1100&049113082705515646000190&0]
```

The start delimiter is ' _ '  and end delimiter is '&'. I require all substrings that comes between '_' and '&'. i.e., my output should be:

```
SRT    USB_3.0_JET_16G    1100
```

I tried using boost::tokenizer, but it tokenizes the string 'USB_3.0_JET_16G' also, as it contains ' _ '. So my aim is whatever comes in between '_' and '&' should be a part of the substring and if there exists more than one start and end delimiters, all of those substrings should be retrieved.

How to do this? I am using VS 2010.

Thank You

Comment: There are many possible solutions to this, what have you tried so far? How did it work? How didn't it work?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : I used boost::tokenizer by specifying `boost::char_separator<char> sep("_&]");`. But it splitted the second subtring that I required further depending on the occurence of '_'.

Comment: It may be possible to read the substrings using simple loops. But I prefer library functions to do it.

Comment: In this case you maybe don't have a choice, considering one of the substring contains one of the separator characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to do it in two passes: First you tokenize on the `'&'` characters, which is easy since none of your wanted substrings contain that character.

Then in the second pass you simply discard any text up to (and including) the first `'_'` character from the substrings you got in the first pass.